# How can java packages be named after its path and folder name at the same time?

Tags: java, maven, directory, package, naming

I have created a project with the Maven directory structure and made a package folder called `machine` in `src/main/java/machine`.

In the class source file `src/main/java/machine/MyClass.java` I have defined the package as follows at the top of the file:

```
package main.java.machine;
```

However, when I try to compile my Main.java file which is outside of the package with the statement

```
import main.java.machine.MyClass;
```

I get a compile error "symbol not found" when i try to instantiate an object from MyClass.

I don't understand how I can follow the naming convention of naming packages after their directory path, while at the same time naming them after the enclosing folder (in my case that would be `package machine;`, which works).

I tried doing the same thing in a real Maven project with IntelliJ IDEA, and the IDE prompts me to either create a new package folder with the name `java.machine.MyClass` or rename the package to `machine` in the statement at the top of the MyClass.java file.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Maven* default source folder is `src/main/java/`, so all your packages must be included in that folder. Instead, the one related to test, should be included in `src/main/test`.

For example, in your case, if you have created the package machine, your class under that package must have the following statement:

```
package machine;
```

Instead, all classes that want to import the classes inside machine package will import it in this way:

```
import machine;
```

However, as best practice, try to start a package name with a "domain", followed by the name of your project, then you can differentiate each package by its own purpose. For example, a classic package coud be `com.myproject.machine`

Comment: How would I do it if I was not using maven and did it all manually? If I make the directory path src/main/java/machine/MyClass in the terminal and call the package main.java.machine in the MyClass.java file, I still have the problem of not finding the package. Must i set the source folder by using some command? When i search I mostly find about classpath

Comment: Basically, if you use `javac` command, you should use `-sourcepath` option to specify the folder where the source code is located. The command should appear like this: `javac -sourcepath main/java --classpath <location of jars and bytecodes> machine/MyClass.java`